# not able to scrape review score from airbnb using Rvest

Tags: r, rvest

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)


page = "https://www.airbnb.ae/rooms/585742764031233504?preview_for_ml=true&source_impression_id=p3_1660929108_esIxWS5HCyk890Im"

### for average Review score
page %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes("._17p6nbba") %>% html_text2()


### for review count
page %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes("span._s65ijh7") %>% html_text2()
```

Both are returning "character(0)"

Comment: The page loads dynamic website contents and can't be scraped the 'conventional' way.

Comment: any other way?? using R

Comment: I know of 'RSelenium' and depending on the data returned 'jsonlite'. I would recommend to google around to get an overview.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this in `JSON` format with Selenium:

```r
library(rvest)
library(jsonlite)

json1 <- read_html("https://www.airbnb.ae/rooms/585742764031233504?preview_for_ml=true&source_impression_id=p3_1660929108_esIxWS5HCyk890Im") %>%
  html_element(xpath = "/html/body//script[@id='data-deferred-state']") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  fromJSON()

json1$niobeMinimalClientData[[1]][[2]]$data$presentation$stayProductDetailPage$sections$metadata$loggingContext$eventDataLogging
```

The trick I learned for these instances is to download the raw HTML with `read_html(url)`, write it to disk with `xml2::write_html` and then open with Chrome, inspect, command f for the search term (such as 4.50), get that element, and then parse the `JSON`.